# Delete many records from table A and B with one FK to table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I have 2 tables: `A` and `B`

`A` contains the following columns:

```
Id [uniqueIdentifier] -PK
checkpointId [numeric(20,0)]
```

`B` contains the following:

```
Id [uniqueIdentifier] – PK
A_id (FK, uniqueIdentifier)
```

`B` has a reference to `A` from `A_id` column (FK)

The question:
I want to delete all records from table `A` that their `checkpoint_id` is less than `X`:

```
delete from CheckpointStorageObject where checkpointIdentifierIdentifier <= 1000
```

But I can't do it since `"The primary key value cannot be deleted because references to this key still exist"`

I tried to delete first from `B` table without a join:

```
DELETE FROM CheckpointToProtectionGroup 
WHERE EXIST (SELECT * from CheckpointStorageObject 
             WHERE CheckpointStorageObject.CheckpointIdentifierIdentifier <= 1000)
```

But it didn't work.

How can I do it?
Is it possible to delete from both table with one execute commands?

The resulted deleted records may be very big - more than 30K records in each table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

First delete from tableB:

```
delete from tableB where A_id IN (Select Id from tableA where checkpointId <= 1000)
```

And then delete from tableA:

```
delete from tableA where checkpointId <= 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to delete the entries from table B

```
delete from tableB where A_id IN (Select Id from tableA where checkpointIdentifierIdentifier <= 1000)
```

Once that is done you can delete from table A, by checking the IDs that are no longer in table B

```
delete from tableA where Id not in (select A_id from tableB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second query has some flaws:

- it's `EXISTS` and not `EXIST`
- you need to specify the join condition between the 2 tables. In correlated subqueries like this one, you add thi scondition in the `WHERE` clause
- it's also usfeul to have aliases for the tables, to reduce code and make it more readable, especially with such long names
- enclose the 2 statements in a transaction so you are sure it either succeeds - and delete from both tables - or fail and delete nothing. If you don't use a transaction, the second delete may not succeed, if in the small time between the 2 deletes, a row is inserted at table B and is refering to a row in table A that you second statement will try to delete.

So, delete first from table B (`CheckpointToProtectionGroup`):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DELETE FROM CheckpointToProtectionGroup AS b
    WHERE EXISTS                                  --- EXISTS
          ( SELECT * 
            FROM CheckpointStorageObject AS a
            WHERE a.id = b.A_id                   --- join condition
              AND a.CheckpointId <= 1000
          ) ;
```

and then from table A (`CheckpointStorageObject`):

```
    DELETE FROM CheckpointStorageObject
    WHERE CheckpointId <= 1000 ;

COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
```